# Why training loss is not low even though mAP is quite high?

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, caffe

I have a small network as follow. I have 1400 trained images and 350 test images. I trained from scratch without any pretrained weight.
Actually it is same as [SSD](https://github.com/weiliu89/caffe/tree/ssd) and just that network architecture is changed. So loss function is also same as SSD.

```
name: "train"
layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "AnnotatedData"
  top: "data"
  top: "label"
  include {
    phase: TRAIN
  }
  transform_param {
    mirror: false
    mean_value: 109.0
    mean_value: 110.0
    mean_value: 110.0
    resize_param {
      prob: 1.0
      resize_mode: WARP
      height: 480
      width: 480
      interp_mode: LINEAR
      interp_mode: AREA
      interp_mode: NEAREST
      interp_mode: CUBIC
      interp_mode: LANCZOS4
      height_scale: 480
      width_scale: 480
    }
    emit_constraint {
      emit_type: CENTER
    }
    distort_param {
      brightness_prob: 0.5
      brightness_delta: 32.0
      contrast_prob: 0.5
      contrast_lower: 0.5
      contrast_upper: 1.5
      hue_prob: 0.5
      hue_delta: 18.0
      saturation_prob: 0.5
      saturation_lower: 0.5
      saturation_upper: 1.5
      random_order_prob: 0.0
    }
    expand_param {
      prob: 0.5
      max_expand_ratio: 4.0
    }
  }
  data_param {
    source: "/home/coie/data/NumberPlate/lmdb/Nextan_trainval_lmdb"
    batch_size: 16
    backend: LMDB
  }
  annotated_data_param {
    batch_sampler {
      max_sample: 1
      max_trials: 1
    }
    batch_sampler {
      sampler {
        min_scale: 0.300000011921
        max_scale: 1.0
        min_aspect_ratio: 0.5
        max_aspect_ratio: 2.0
      }
      sample_constraint {
        min_jaccard_overlap: 0.5
      }
      max_sample: 1
      max_trials: 50
    }
    batch_sampler {
      sampler {
        min_scale: 0.300000011921
        max_scale: 1.0
        min_aspect_ratio: 0.5
        max_aspect_ratio: 2.0
      }
      sample_constraint {
        min_jaccard_overlap: 0.699999988079
      }
      max_sample: 1
      max_trials: 50
    }
    batch_sampler {
      sampler {
        min_scale: 0.300000011921
        max_scale: 1.0
        min_aspect_ratio: 0.5
        max_aspect_ratio: 2.0
      }
      sample_constraint {
        min_jaccard_overlap: 0.899999976158
      }
      max_sample: 1
      max_trials: 50
    }
    batch_sampler {
      sampler {
        min_scale: 0.300000011921
        max_scale: 1.0
        min_aspect_ratio: 0.5
        max_aspect_ratio: 2.0
      }
      sample_constraint {
        max_jaccard_overlap: 1.0
      }
      max_sample: 1
      max_trials: 50
    }
    label_map_file: "/home/coie/data/NumberPlate/labelmap_NumberPlate.prototxt"
  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv1"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "data"
  top: "conv1"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1.0
    decay_mult: 1.0
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2.0
    decay_mult: 0.0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 6
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0.0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu1"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv1"
  top: "conv1"
}
layer {
  name: "conv2"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "conv1"
  top: "conv2"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1.0
    decay_mult: 1.0
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2.0
    decay_mult: 0.0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 6
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0.0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu2"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv2"
  top: "conv2"
}
layer {
  name: "pool2"
  type: "Pooling"
  bottom: "conv2"
  top: "pool2"
  pooling_param {
    pool: MAX
    kernel_size: 3
    stride: 3
  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv3"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "pool2"
  top: "conv3"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1.0
    decay_mult: 1.0
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2.0
    decay_mult: 0.0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 16
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0.0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu3"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv3"
  top: "conv3"
}
layer {
  name: "pool3"
  type: "Pooling"
  bottom: "conv3"
  top: "pool3"
  pooling_param {
    pool: MAX
    kernel_size: 2
    stride: 2
  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv4"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "pool3"
  top: "conv4"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1.0
    decay_mult: 1.0
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2.0
    decay_mult: 0.0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 32
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0.0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu4"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv4"
  top: "conv4"
}
layer {
  name: "pool4"
  type: "Pooling"
  bottom: "conv4"
  top: "pool4"
  pooling_param {
    pool: MAX
    kernel_size: 2
    stride: 2
  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv5"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "pool4"
  top: "conv5"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1.0
    decay_mult: 1.0
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2.0
    decay_mult: 0.0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 64
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0.0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu5"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv5"
  top: "conv5"
}
layer {
  name: "pool5"
  type: "Pooling"
  bottom: "conv5"
  top: "pool5"
  pooling_param {
    pool: MAX
    kernel_size: 2
    stride: 2
  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv6"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "pool5"
  top: "conv6"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1.0
    decay_mult: 1.0
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2.0
    decay_mult: 0.0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 64
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0.0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu6"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv6"
  top: "conv6"
}
layer {
  name: "pool6"
  type: "Pooling"
  bottom: "conv6"
  top: "pool6"
  pooling_param {
    pool: MAX
    kernel_size: 2
    stride: 2
  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv7"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "pool6"
  top: "conv7"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1.0
    decay_mult: 1.0
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2.0
    decay_mult: 0.0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 64
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0.0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu7"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "conv7"
  top: "conv7"
}
layer {
  name: "conv6_norm"
  type: "Normalize"
  bottom: "conv6"
  top: "conv6_norm"
  norm_param {
    across_spatial: false
    scale_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 20.0
    }
    channel_shared: false
  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv6_norm_mbox_loc"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "conv6_norm"
  top: "conv6_norm_mbox_loc"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1.0
    decay_mult: 1.0
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2.0
    decay_mult: 0.0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 12
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    stride: 1
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0.0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv6_norm_mbox_loc_perm"
  type: "Permute"
  bottom: "conv6_norm_mbox_loc"
  top: "conv6_norm_mbox_loc_perm"
  permute_param {
    order: 0
    order: 2
    order: 3
    order: 1
  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv6_norm_mbox_loc_flat"
  type: "Flatten"
  bottom: "conv6_norm_mbox_loc_perm"
  top: "conv6_norm_mbox_loc_flat"
  flatten_param {
    axis: 1
  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv6_norm_mbox_conf"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "conv6_norm"
  top: "conv6_norm_mbox_conf"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1.0
    decay_mult: 1.0
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2.0
    decay_mult: 0.0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 6
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    stride: 1
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0.0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv6_norm_mbox_conf_perm"
  type: "Permute"
  bottom: "conv6_norm_mbox_conf"
  top: "conv6_norm_mbox_conf_perm"
  permute_param {
    order: 0
    order: 2
    order: 3
    order: 1
  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv6_norm_mbox_conf_flat"
  type: "Flatten"
  bottom: "conv6_norm_mbox_conf_perm"
  top: "conv6_norm_mbox_conf_flat"
  flatten_param {
    axis: 1
  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv6_norm_mbox_priorbox"
  type: "PriorBox"
  bottom: "conv6_norm"
  bottom: "data"
  top: "conv6_norm_mbox_priorbox"
  prior_box_param {
    min_size: 20.0
    max_size: 40.0
    aspect_ratio: 2.0
    flip: false
    clip: false
    variance: 0.10000000149
    variance: 0.10000000149
    variance: 0.20000000298
    variance: 0.20000000298
    img_size: 480
    step: 24.0
    offset: 0.5
  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv7_norm"
  type: "Normalize"
  bottom: "conv7"
  top: "conv7_norm"
  norm_param {
    across_spatial: false
    scale_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 20.0
    }
    channel_shared: false
  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv7_norm_mbox_loc"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "conv7_norm"
  top: "conv7_norm_mbox_loc"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1.0
    decay_mult: 1.0
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2.0
    decay_mult: 0.0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 12
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    stride: 1
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0.0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv7_norm_mbox_loc_perm"
  type: "Permute"
  bottom: "conv7_norm_mbox_loc"
  top: "conv7_norm_mbox_loc_perm"
  permute_param {
    order: 0
    order: 2
    order: 3
    order: 1
  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv7_norm_mbox_loc_flat"
  type: "Flatten"
  bottom: "conv7_norm_mbox_loc_perm"
  top: "conv7_norm_mbox_loc_flat"
  flatten_param {
    axis: 1
  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv7_norm_mbox_conf"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "conv7_norm"
  top: "conv7_norm_mbox_conf"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1.0
    decay_mult: 1.0
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2.0
    decay_mult: 0.0
  }
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 6
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    stride: 1
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      value: 0.0
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv7_norm_mbox_conf_perm"
  type: "Permute"
  bottom: "conv7_norm_mbox_conf"
  top: "conv7_norm_mbox_conf_perm"
  permute_param {
    order: 0
    order: 2
    order: 3
    order: 1
  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv7_norm_mbox_conf_flat"
  type: "Flatten"
  bottom: "conv7_norm_mbox_conf_perm"
  top: "conv7_norm_mbox_conf_flat"
  flatten_param {
    axis: 1
  }
}
layer {
  name: "conv7_norm_mbox_priorbox"
  type: "PriorBox"
  bottom: "conv7_norm"
  bottom: "data"
  top: "conv7_norm_mbox_priorbox"
  prior_box_param {
    min_size: 40.0
    max_size: 60.0
    aspect_ratio: 2.0
    flip: false
    clip: false
    variance: 0.10000000149
    variance: 0.10000000149
    variance: 0.20000000298
    variance: 0.20000000298
    img_size: 480
    step: 48.0
    offset: 0.5
  }
}
layer {
  name: "mbox_loc"
  type: "Concat"
  bottom: "conv6_norm_mbox_loc_flat"
  bottom: "conv7_norm_mbox_loc_flat"  
  top: "mbox_loc"
  concat_param {
    axis: 1
  }
}
layer {
  name: "mbox_conf"
  type: "Concat"
  bottom: "conv6_norm_mbox_conf_flat"
  bottom: "conv7_norm_mbox_conf_flat"
  top: "mbox_conf"
  concat_param {
    axis: 1
  }
}
layer {
  name: "mbox_priorbox"
  type: "Concat"
  bottom: "conv6_norm_mbox_priorbox"
  bottom: "conv7_norm_mbox_priorbox"
  top: "mbox_priorbox"
  concat_param {
    axis: 2
  }
}
layer {
  name: "mbox_loss"
  type: "MultiBoxLoss"
  bottom: "mbox_loc"
  bottom: "mbox_conf"
  bottom: "mbox_priorbox"
  bottom: "label"
  top: "mbox_loss"
  include {
    phase: TRAIN
  }
  propagate_down: true
  propagate_down: true
  propagate_down: false
  propagate_down: false
  loss_param {
    normalization: VALID
  }
  multibox_loss_param {
    loc_loss_type: SMOOTH_L1
    conf_loss_type: SOFTMAX
    loc_weight: 1.0
    num_classes: 2
    share_location: true
    match_type: PER_PREDICTION
    overlap_threshold: 0.5
    use_prior_for_matching: true
    background_label_id: 1
    use_difficult_gt: true
    neg_pos_ratio: 3.0
    neg_overlap: 0.5
    code_type: CENTER_SIZE
    ignore_cross_boundary_bbox: false
    mining_type: MAX_NEGATIVE
  }
}
```

I trained for about 5000 iterations. Detection_eval is quite ok 82% and no overfitting.
But loss is not low around 5. What should I do to reduce the loss?
Training loss and iterations, Learning rate and iterations are attached.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This may be a partial answer. Maybe it will help.

I notice a few things:

- you are not using pre-trained weights. You should probably use it. The network will converge faster, potentially to a better evaluation loss.
- your training set is quite small. It's weird that you are not really overfitting. Are you using some kind of regularisation? It may be too strong. Are you using a strong data augmentation? If no, you may want to do this.

Are you using a custom architecture network ? It may be toosmall for the task at end. Maybe add more layers. In general you should be able to see overfitting appearing on your training loss with large networks and small eval set.

I see you don't show the evaluation loss. Do you have it ?